# How to resolver Arquilian on wildfly test problem under windows

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I have a problem related to testing in windows operating system using Idea, I use Arquilian on wildfly server, the error i'm getting is this    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:33390. The connection timed out]
[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:33390. The connection timed out]
[org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer] WARN: Cannot undeploy: project-in-ear.ear

Comment: Is the management endpoint listening on port 33390?

Comment: yes i know what you mean, yes the management endpoint is listening on port 33390

Comment: Is the server shutdown before the deployment is removed?

Comment: [INFO] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 33388
[INFO] Running org.myOrganization.project.it.test.validating.AcceptProblemValuesTest
[org.reflections.Reflections] INFO: Reflections took 117 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 106 values 
[org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.DeploymentClassFinder] INFO: arquillian-suite-deployment: Found class annotated with @ArquillianSuiteDeployment: org.myOrganization.project.it.ProjectTest

Comment: [org.jboss.threads] INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
[javax.management.mbeanserver] ERROR: The LogManager accessed before the "java.util.logging.manager" system property was set to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager". Results may be unexpected.
[org.jboss.remoting] INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.19.Final
[org.xnio] INFO: XNIO version 3.8.2.Final
[org.xnio.nio] INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.2.Final
[org.wildfly.security] INFO: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.19.1.Final

Comment: This is what is showing when doing the test with Maven and debugging the remote jvm 33388

Comment: the serve doesn't shutdown before deployment is removed

Comment: What the error is saying is that it can't connect to the server for some reason. It's hard to know without a reproducer why that would be.

Comment: I mean that this is related to just the env of windows because on Linux machine this work fine

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what I see is that the problem is with firewall rules; you can try to add the ip and port authorization and see if this work

Comment: Thanks I have tried what you told me, it doesn't resolve the problem